# How do I get Linux to use pcie m.2 interface with ssd

Tags: ssd, pci-express, m2-connector, ngff

I bought a PCIe m.2 interface for one of my SSDs. When I load up linux, the drive does not appear in the output of `lsblk`.

I can find the interface in `lspci`. If I physically remove the card from the motherboard, the entry
`00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4)` disappears from the `lspci` output.

So a quick `lspci -v` gives:
`00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27 Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0 I/O behind bridge: [disabled] Memory behind bridge: [disabled] Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] Capabilities: <access denied> Kernel driver in use: pcieport`

Also, I've looked through the BIOS and can't see the SSD anywhere. This is supposed to support NGFF (SATA), which I can see printed on the interface. The drive is NGFF (SATA) as well (WD NAS Red SA500 M.2). So unless I've misunderstood, these should be compatible.

Is there any way to activate this so I can use the drive?

Is the solution to just have the correct driver? It's a cheap interface from ebay (not even sure if it has a brand) so I'm guessing they never made a linux driver. I'd rather not buy another, but if that's necessary, can anyone suggest one that works with linux? The motherboard is an old lenovo m83.

Comment: I have a Lenovo TS140 machine that boots from a m.2 SSD. It uses the drive as the boot drive, though. I don't recall having any difficulty in getting the drive detected with [this PCIe connector](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JKH5VTL/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_N6jaFbDVFBENB), bought at $16.99 from Amazon. The machine runs Linux Mint.

Comment: Have you tried running your partitioning software? Note that you have to 1. format the drive (`gnome-disks` [GUI: `disks`] or `gparted`) and then 2. `mount ...` it.  (Shell/Terminal commands, also runable from the GUI)

Comment: `fdisk -l, gparted, parted, lsblk` - none of these can see the drive